# How to make livewire loading work with browser event

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

wire:loading does not work on wire:model input when the event is fired from the browser

My livewire component view:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" wire:loading.attr="disabled" wire:model.defer="schedule_comment"/>

window.livewire.emit('modalOpen', data );
```

My livewire controller:

```
protected $listeners = ['modalOpen' => 'updateModal'];

public function updateModal(MyModel $MyModel)
    {
        //doing work
    }
```